# C# Datarepeater check Textbox Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datarepeater

I have a C# Datarepeator on my Form1 and I bind it dynamically with Binding Source. and everything is fine by displaying the data. 
Now I have to check an textbox value for each item in the repeater using if statement and if true then I should write a value in a label control on the same item of the repeater.

My code is as following:

```
private void btn_search_DE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_tech_approval.DataBindings.Clear();
    txt_tech_approval.DataBindings.Add("Text", bSource, "Username", false, 
                                        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

   switch (txt_tech_approval.Text)
   {
        case "CE":
            lbl_CE.Text = "X";
            break;
    }   
}
```

how can i solve it?

thanks alot .

Comment: Is it a `web form` or `win form`?

Comment: it is Win Form using C#

Comment: Please i need your help guys, i didn't find any resource for that in WinForms

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585944/combobox-on-datarepeater-control-shares-selected-index